# pyparsing: Each using Optional with default issue

Tags: python, default, option-type, pyparsing

I need to parse configuraion file where configurations commands may be omitted (so I want to use `Optional` with `default`) and have no particular order (so I have to use `Each`). Anyway, let's start with an ordered configuration:

```
teststr = """
interface 4
  frames tagged
exit
interface 5
  pvid 17
exit
"""

portid = Word(nums)('portid')
pvid = Keyword('pvid').suppress() + Word(nums)('pvid')
frames = Keyword('frames').suppress() \
    + (Keyword('tagged') | Keyword('all'))

exit = Keyword('exit')

interface = Group(
    Keyword('interface') + portid  \
        + Optional(pvid) \
        + Optional(frames, default='all')('frames') \
        + exit
    )

interface_list = Group(interface + ZeroOrMore(interface))('interfaces')

res = interface_list.parseString(teststr)

for iface in res.interfaces:
    print '{}\n'.format(iface.dump())
```

This code gives me this result (which is ok, I believe --- please note that `frames` set to `tagged` for the first section):

```
['interface', '4', 'tagged', 'exit']
- frames: ['tagged']
- portid: 4

['interface', '5', '17', 'all', 'exit']
- frames: ['all']
- portid: 5
- pvid: 17
```

But **now** I want to parse this configuration assuming that commands `pvid` and `frames` may go in any order, so I want to **use `Each`** this way:

```
interface = pp.Group(
    pp.Keyword('interface') + portid + (
            pp.Optional(pvid) 
          & pp.Optional(frames, default='all')('frames')
        ) + exit)
```

And now I get wrong (I do believe) result:

```
['interface', '4', 'tagged', 'all', 'exit']
- frames: ['all']
- portid: 4

['interface', '5', '17', 'all', 'all', 'exit']
- frames: ['all', 'all']
- portid: 5
- pvid: 17
```

I would expect `pyparsing` to return the same result as it was using `And` operator. Am I wrong? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What version of pyparsing are you using?  With pyparsing 2.0.3, with your sample program, I get:

```
['interface', '4', 'tagged', 'exit']
- frames: ['tagged']
- portid: 4

['interface', '5', '17', 'all', 'exit']
- frames: ['all']
- portid: 5
- pvid: 17
```

Comment: Version: 2.0.1+dfsg1-1build1 (ubuntu). Thank you for your reply. I'll check :)

Comment: No ,( After `apt-get remove python-pyparsing` and `pip install pyparsing` and adding `print pyparsing.__version__` --- I have the same [wrong] result so far. Tried to re-login to avoid any caching or I don't know what else. The same result still. Wouldn't like to be wrong, but it looks like I've checked things twice and twice again. I mean wrong output when using `&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've got 2.0.3 and applied this patch to it:

```
--- pyparsing-2.0.3.py  2015-07-16 17:30:16.705011488 +0300
+++ pyparsing-2.0.3-patched.py  2015-07-16 17:35:03.977015739 +0300
@@ -2811,6 +2811,9 @@
         self.defaultValue = default
         self.mayReturnEmpty = True

+        if self.defaultValue is not _optionalNotMatched:
+            self.mayReturnEmpty = False
+
     def parseImpl( self, instring, loc, doActions=True ):
         try:
             loc, tokens = self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
```

Then I've changed the definition for `interface`:

```
interface = pp.Group(
    pp.Keyword('interface') + portid + (
            pp.Optional(pvid)
          & pp.Optional(frames('frames'), default='all')
        ) + exit)
```

This gives me the most "intuitive" result, I'd say:

```
['interface', '4', 'tagged', 'exit']
- frames: ['tagged']
- portid: 4

['interface', '5', '17', 'all', 'exit']
- frames: all
- portid: 5
- pvid: 17
```

That patch does not break any [more] tests in current svn. Anyway I am not sure that I know what I am doing, so I am still looking for an answer.

@paul-mcguire, sorry, upgrading to 2.0.3 didn't help me.

And THANK you .)